# Leaflet.js union/merge circles

Tags: javascript, merge, geometry, leaflet, union

I draw a lot of circles onto a map using Leaflet.js. Sometimes many of these circles overlap. Even though the circles are transparent (CSS opacity set to 0.3), the map then cannot be seen properly anymore.
I am looking for a way to create one figure out of n circles. I found [Greiner Hormann](https://github.com/w8r/GreinerHormann), however, this seems to work for polygons only.

My question is: How is it possible to union circles that are to be added to a leaflet.js map.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to perform union operations on `L.circle` objects. What you can do, however, is use [Leaflet Geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy) to create ~circular polygons and perform union operations on those. My suggestion would be to create your circles as `LGeo.circle` objects and place them all in the same layerGroup, e.g.:

```
var cities = new L.LayerGroup();
var chicago = LGeo.circle([41.84, -87.68], 1000000).addTo(cities);
var newOrleans = LGeo.circle([29.95, -90.07], 1000000).addTo(cities);
var denver = LGeo.circle([39.74, -104.99], 1000000).addTo(cities);
```

This is handy because once they are grouped together, you can use `.getLayers()` to get an array of all the layers, then iterate over them to get their union. This function, for example, will take an array of your layers and return a `L.geoJson` object of their union, calculated with [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/):

```
function unify(polyList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < polyList.length; ++i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      var unionTemp = polyList[i].toGeoJSON();
    } else {
      unionTemp = turf.union(unionTemp, polyList[i].toGeoJSON());
    }
  }
  return L.geoJson(unionTemp);
}

var cityUnion = unify(cities.getLayers()).addTo(map);
```

Here is an example fiddle of this at work:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/ehpL8fho/

[ While using Turf is probably the better solution, if you want to try using Greiner Hormann instead, here is an [example fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/gc4Lx80c/) using that. You may notice that this produces an error if you try it with circles that are not all overlapping. This is because the Greiner Hormann routine returns nothing when the input polygons do not overlap. Using Turf will avoid this problem, because its union routine handles non-contiguous polygons by returning a multipolygon object instead. ]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I really appreciate it. This is exactly what I was looking for.I will use the solution with turf as it might be that there are circles that do not overlap.

Comment: You're quite welcome! If this ends up solving your problem, please do accept the answer.

Comment: @nathansnider your fiddles are gone! I had no idea they might expire, do you by chance have a similar code snippet around?